# Delta sync of calendarView doesn't include deleted occurrences of a recurring event

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

I've got a solution working that is pulling in a calendarView of events, and then using delta sync to track changes and keep the list up to date.

However, I'm noticing some strange behavior with recurring events. Specifically, if I delete one occurrence of a recurring event, **the next delta sync will have a copy of every other occurrence but simply nothing for the deleted occurrence**.

When I delete a non-recurring event, I properly get back an entry from the delta sync with the @removed property set (as expected).

Without this working, the delta sync is unusable as I will never know to remove these deleted events from my storage, and they will continue to be displayed. Can this be addressed? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the app receives a recurring series in the deltasync response, the app should remove the already sync'ed instances of the series and re-sync the series instances.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Perhaps it's worth including that in the documentation as it definitely threw me for a loop!

Comment: Bumping this comment, I don't recall seeing this mentioned explicitly anywhere but I could have missed it. This is a pretty big detail to leave for the implementer to learn about the hard way. I get _why_ this makes sense but it needs to be clearly communicated.